# What is the purpose of comment voting?

Tags: discussion, comment-voting

What is the real purpose of comment voting? As far as I see, there is no use for voting for comments (other than the Pundit badge)? In fact, you can only vote up comments (as opposed to questions and answers "the other icon" does not vote down, but flags as offensive).

---

#### Edit:

This question is not "What is the purpose of comments?". I am asking about comment voting.

Comment: **[Obligatory witty comment]**

Comment: I don't see anyone here answering "What is the purpose of comments?". You do seem to be confused about that though.

Comment: @Rich B - this edit is addressing some yet deleted comments people added. So I wanted to make it perfectly clear.

Comment: @smok1: What deleted comments? Oh my...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Jeff Atwood made this very clear when he introduced the feature:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/

Comment: I'm glad they changed the way the comments are presented.  That old interface was way too bulky.

Comment: Your answer and TheTXI's comment answer my question.

Answer (score 7):

When there are a lot of comments in a thread, only the highest rated ones will be shown by default. Comment voting helps filter out the useful ones from the noise.

Comment: And you end up with having few coments regarding some other comment visible (this comment wasn't voted so high, so it is invisble)...

Comment: @smok1: The rest is considered noise. You can always expand the full list if you think you are missing something.

Answer (score 6):

It reduces "me too" commenting, because you can add emphasis to the one you like by voting for it.

Answer (score 5):

So that my witty comments filter to the top.

Comment: We only upvote your comments so people can be immediately subjected to your...brilliance.

Comment: Even if your witty comment did not address the question/answer, but other (probably less rated) COMMENT?

Comment: @smok1: You do understand comments != answers, right?

Comment: I understand. But, as I remeber my old Usenet days - answers for plonked post, were also considered a trash. So unless we have got comments threading, I see no point in voting comments.

Comment: @smok1: 1) You are going to have to start speaking English, I can barely understand your ramblings. 2) This is not Usenet. 3) Comments work fine.

Comment: @Rich B - As I remember people in Usenet did not like other people responding to “trash” (spam, trolling, etc) post, since answering trash produced more and more stupid flame wars. I hope this is understandable. I won’t explain “plonk” (hence “plonked”), “trolling” or “flame war” since you can find it in Wikipedia.
My point is, that unless comments are threaded, I see no point in voting up comments, that are only answers to someone else’s comment.I also think no one does not see difference between SO and Usenet. Comments are working fine, but I simply wanted to know why they work that way.

Comment: Comments were not designed to be full blown threaded discussions, and it is unlikely that you will ever see that incorporated into these sites. If you want to see the full-blown discussion, expand and read. Otherwise the comment voting is meant to single out the comments that the most people agree with (or felt the urge to upvote).

Comment: @smok1: And this has been answered several times for you, but you are continuing to argue and rant about the way it works.

Comment: SO is /not/ a discussion site. Read that, and repeat it back to yourself a few times.

Comment: @Rich B - I asked simple question, but in fact, you were unable to answer it in polite and accurate way. TheTXI's comment is simply the most complete answer. Thank you, TheTXI.

Comment: @smok1: The community seems to disagree.

Comment: @smok1: For those annoying, pesky problems on SO and Meta, try this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/greasemonkey-ignore-user-script-now-includes-lists

It has made my (and others') SO experience MUCH more pleasant.

Answer (score 3):

I know it makes me feel good and more confident when I get a comment upvote.  If I get enough, then maybe I'll have enough confidence to leave the house some day.

Comment: You would be doing the world a disservice.

Comment: Are you going to wear pants if you venture outside?

Comment: @Rich B: One thing at a time, man.

Comment: @btk: I am only concerned about the order.

Comment: @Rich: Actually, I'll probably be wearing a winter coat, ski pants, and a <st>retard</st> football helmet.  I have to protect myself from scary things that are outside.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to allowing popular comments to be promoted I believe comment voting can also be used as a form of [phatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic) expression.

> In linguistics, a phatic expression is one whose only function is to perform a social task, as opposed to conveying information. The term was coined by anthropologist Bronisław Malinowski in the early 1900s.
>
> For example, "you're welcome" is not intended to convey the message that the hearer is welcome; it is a phatic response to being thanked, which in turn is a phatic whose function is to be polite in response to a gift.

or to put more succinctly to be phatic is to be "full of social gestures that are like apes grooming each other"<sup>[1](http://epeus.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-twitter-works-in-theory.html)</sup>

I've often upvoted comments on my own answers that were thanking me for an answer as a feedback to the OP that I have read it and appreciate the thanks. At least I hope that's how it would be interpreted as I was the only person that would be interested in the comment.

Comment: Regarding last sentence: comments thanking for an answer *may* have some usefulness outside of being polite - often such a comment makes it clearer that the answer indeed provided useful advice for the OP, which may helpful for future readers. But overall good point.

Comment: NB: I found the blog post I quote via a discussion in TWIG: http://wiki.twit.tv/wiki/This_WEEK_in_GOOGLE_3/Transcript#17:54 (I actually stopped and posted this before SO was mentioned.)