# Voting to close as duplicate removes voting controls from auto-comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, comment-voting

I believe this happens under the following conditions:

- Vote to close as a duplicate
- There was an existing "possible duplicate of" auto-comment for the same target question as I voted

The voting controls on at least the auto-comment* are gone after clicking through the "this question needs n more votes ..." message until the page is refreshed.

<sub>* I did it twice, but there was only a single auto-comment on both questions.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of comment voting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13738/what-is-the-purpose-of-comment-voting)

Comment: Other test comment.

Comment: You don't have any voting controls on your own comments -- but you're right; it's broken on all comments.

Comment: @balpha: It was so other people could test. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I only brought back half of the functionality when I reenabled the "possible duplicate of" comment auto-refresh thingadongdong yesterday.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Whats your build path, like when to you release new fixes and patches for the site(s)?

Comment: @Justin usually about 1-5 times a day (unless it's urgent we try not to deploy Stack Overflow itself during US business day when it's the busiest; meta usually gets a few more builds)