# Ignore questions from specific users

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

There are some SO users which keep posting same questions, over and over, despites all them being closed.

Is possible to create a feature to hide messages from specific users, just like "Ignored Tags" feature?

Comment: If you happen upon your self Firefox with a Greasy monkey: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script

Answer (score 0):

You should report that type of behavior. Don't ignore it.