# Private profile tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think it would be nice to have the ability to attach tags to user profiles. Private ones.

So I can mark the user as a `troll` and next time I see his replies - I don't even start talking to him.

(Yes, I've been attacked by some troll for the second time today)

Comment: Did you try flagging his content for moderator attention?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Yes I did, but this doesn't prevent me from talkting to him next time. I think it would be nice to store private notes about person (since I am not able to keep in mind all bad people's names)

Comment: I agree with Andrew. Moderators should be able to solve problems like this for the benefit of *all* users, not just you. I'd prefer not to get attacked, and I certainly don't want to have something else I have to manage in order to accomplish it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I proposed some private notes. Like `Java-hater` for example. To know in the future that it is not a good idea to discuss him about java. I've got bad mood today after the talking to that troll. How moderator supposed to protect me from that? Well, they arent. The best way was to not even answer him, but I forgot who he is and made that mistake :-(

Comment: You could try this [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xsticky-addon-sticky-notes/).

Comment: @alex: /me is a chrome user :-S But analogy is great. That is what I want.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, I use Chrome too :) How about [this](http://www.chromeplugins.org/extensions/chrome-sticky-notes-extension-write-save-and-view-notes-from-the-browser/)? :)

Comment: The idea is that if a particular user is hostile and unnecessarily argumentative (enough to really upset you), a moderator could send that person a private message, asking them to chill out. If they do this with you, they probably do it with everyone. They might not even realize that you consider their behavior "trolling", or they might be intentionally trolling, in which case they're an asshole and there needs to be action taken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add the ability to ignore users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users). Also see: [Ignore Users Script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)